Smoothness of Ricci flow solution on a closed interval
In the paper "Deforming the metric on complete Riemannian manifolds" by Wan-Xiong Shi, the author proves the following theorem which I copy verbatim below:

Theorem 1.1. Let $(M, g_{ij}(x)$ be an $n$-dimensional complete noncompact Riemannian manifold with its Riemannian curvature tensor $\{R_{ijkl}$ satisfying
$$|R_{ijkl}|^2 \leq k_0$$
on $M$, where $0 < k_0 < + \infty$ is a constant. Then there exists a constant $T(n,k_0) > 0$ depending only on $n$ and $k_0$ such that the evolution equation
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} g_{ij}(x,t) = -2 R_{ij}(x,t)\quad  \text{on $M$,}$$
$$g_{ij}(x,0) = g_{ij}(x) \quad \forall x \in M$$
has a smooth solution $g_{ij}(x,t) > 0$ for a short time $0 \leq t \leq T(n,k_0)$.

I understand that if $I\subseteq \mathbb R$ is an open interval, then smoothness of a Ricci flow solution $g:M \times I \rightarrow T^{(0,2)}TM$ means that $g$ is smooth as a map between the smooth manifolds (without boundary) $M \times I$ and $T^{(0,2)}TM$.
Question. What does Shi mean by smooth when he says $g:M \times I \rightarrow T^{(0,2)}TM$  a smooth solution to the Ricci flow, where $I = [0,T]$ is a closed interval?
I have a couple of guesses as to what he means by smooth.

We consider $M \times [0,T]$ as a smooth manifold with boundary, then consider $g:M \times [0,T] \rightarrow T^{(0,2)}TM$ as a smooth map as defined in Chapter 2 of Lee's Smooth Manifolds.
$g:M \times [0,T] \rightarrow T^{(0,2)}TM$ is smooth on $M \times (0,T)$, and the metrics $g(-,t)$ converge in $C^\infty$ on compact subsets to $g(0)$ as $t \rightarrow 0^+$ and $g(-,t)$ converge in $C^\infty$ on compact subsets to $g(T)$ as $t \rightarrow T^-$ as defined in Definition 3.2 of the Ricci Flow: Techniques and Applications Part 1.

I tried reading the proof of Theorem 1.1 but it didn't help me understand what Shi means by smooth.

Both are correct and equivalent. It all boils down to this: In local coordinates $(x^1, \dots, x^n)$ on an open $U \subset M$, the components of the metric tensor $$ g_{ij}(x^1, \dots, x^n,t), $$ and its partial derivatives of all orders with respect to $x$ and $t$ for $(x,t) \in U\times (0,T)$ extend continuously to $U\times (0,T]$. This, in particular, implies that at $t=T$, the 1-sided derivatives with respect to $t$ exists and is the limit of the derivative when $t < T$.
